# PHP if, else if, else logic

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make a BMI calculator...so far, I have everything displaying properly, except for the actual BMI range (below, normal, above).

There's most likely an issue with my if/elseif statements, because the output is always wrong.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $weight = $_POST['txtWeight'];
    $height = $_POST['txtHeight'];

    $selected_unit = $_POST['optUnit'];

    $metric_status = 'unchecked';
    $imperial_status = 'unchecked';

    $impCalc = ($weight * 703) / ($height * $height);
    $metCalc = $weight / ($height * $height);
    $below = 'below average.';
    $normal = 'normal.';
    $above = 'above average.';

    if (($impCalc < 18.5) || ($metCalc < 18.5))
        {
         $bmi = $below;
        }

    elseif (($impCalc >= 18.5 && $impCalc <= 24.9) || ($metCalc >= 18.5 || $metCalc <= 24.9))
        {
         $bmi = $normal;
        }

    else
        {
         $bmi = $above;
        }

    if (isset($_POST['btnEnter']))
        {
         $selected_unit = $_POST['optUnit'];
         if($selected_unit == 'imperial')
            {
             $imperial_status = 'checked';
             echo "A height of {$height} inches and a weight of {$weight} pounds = {$impCalc} BMI.  Your BMI calc is: {$bmi}";
            }
        else if($selected_unit =='metric')
            {
             $metric_status = 'checked';
             echo "A height of {$height} meters and a weight of {$weight} kilograms: {$metCalc} BMI.  Your BMI calc is: {$bmi}";
            }
        }


?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have two radio buttons on my form so that the user can choose metric (meters and kilograms) or imperial (inches and pounds).  I want it to be able to calculate based on which method is selected (imperial BMI is calculated by (weight * 703) / (height * height) and metric is weight / (height * height).  My outputs are always wonky (it does the BMI calculation correctly, at least from what I've seen), but when I need it to ouput below, normal, or above, it always shows the wrong thing.

Comment: Well, how should _we_ say what is wrong? You don't say what the problem is apart from "is wrong". _What_ is wrong? What should be different?

Comment: Syntactially it's okay. What's bad? Bad results? Blank page?

Comment: Your obviously getting bad results but could you give me an output example? I mean is it an error in your     ($metCalc >= 18.5 || $metCalc <= 24.9)

Comment: My bad...ok, the output works properly, but any time I input a weight and height to be calculated, it almost always shows up as below average, even if it isn't.  I've had it show up as normal once, but only when I calculated a bmi of 25, which should show up as above average...

Comment: Also, I have 2 radio buttons on my form so that you can enter in imperial(inches and pounds) or metric (meters and kilograms), and that's what those impCalc and metCalc variables are there for (different calculations according to which units).  I'm starting to think that it's not able to differentiate which unit is being used, but I'm not sure how to put that in.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know exactly about BMI, but this line looks very curious:

```
elseif (($impCalc >= 18.5 && $impCalc <= 24.9) || ($metCalc >= 18.5 || $metCalc <= 24.9))
```

I think it should be this:

```
elseif (($impCalc >= 18.5 && $impCalc <= 24.9) || ($metCalc >= 18.5 && $metCalc <= 24.9))
```

Otherwise it would not make sense, because **all** number are met by these criterias.